# Use a Twig variable as a part of an other

Tags: variables, twig

I would like to use a Twig value comes from a "for" loop as a key in another for loop.

I have 2 arrays: "tab" dans "stats".
"tab" array has multiple values, with one named "name", which is an other array with keys and values.
I would like to use the "tab.name" value as a loop variable for my stats array.

I tried with no success to "add" the value directly in my variable.

```
{% for elem in tab %}
{% for data in stats.elem.name %}
------ My code
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

With this I don't have any result because Twig search for "stats.elem.name" array, but in fact for example if in a loop elem.name = "intitule", the real array is stats.intitule.

I hope i'm clear enough… :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Maybe you could show more code.
It seems you just want to make nested loops, but the secund one is not linked with the first one. What look likes an elem dump ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
{% for elem in tab %}
{% for data in stats[elem] %}
{{data}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/mzpjh8

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to add bracket with Twig, so, it's perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the array reference for stats to the standard square brackets - `stats[elem.name]`

```
{% for elem in tab %}
    {% for data in stats[elem.name] %}
        <!-- code -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to add bracket with Twig, so, it's perfect, thank you very much!